# Check if TextBlock has Multiple Lines

Tags: c#, xaml, resize, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` which I want to be as big as possible without being multiple lines.  I need to check to see if it flows onto the next line so that I can reduce the size of the text.  I cannot set the max lines to 1, because then it will just cut off my text.  How Can i see if there are multiple lines being used in my `TextBlock`?

One way I was thinking of, but could not figure out, is something like:

```
if(TextBlock.Text.Width > TextBlock.Width)
```

or

```
if(TextBlock.Height > TextBlock.Text.Height)
```

But those don't seem doable from what I have seen.

Comment: Reducing the font size might give a bad user experience.. consider using scroll bars..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment by bit, but if you wish to do this, you can use a ViewBox control and place the TextBlock inside of it.

```
<Viewbox>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I have been searching for!!  If I add the Stretch="Uniform" property to the XAML, do you know what that does?  It appears to do nothing, which leads me to believe it is the default?

Comment: A Viewbox will take up all the space it is given  :)